# The principal and accountant ……… on leave. (is/are)

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Its **is** on my book and I can’t figure it how. Is it misprint?

Comment: Are both roles performed by the same person?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably

> The principal and accountant **are** on leave

This is because there are 2 people, which is plural, and this question is not an exception to use "is" when it seems plural but in fact uses a **singular pronoun**

E.g.

> Either Tim or Sarah **is** guilty

or

> One of the students **is** studying